# Comparing two files in Unix

Tags: unix

I have got 2 files which have got n number of lines.
eg: File 1

```
465466454
546545454
5454454
Data=4545454545484848484
kuh uytyer huihkuh
```

File 2

```
e4654sdfdsf
544hjklhjl
464jku
Data=4545454545484848484
kuh uytyer huihkuh
```

As you can see both files have got the same data after the place "Data=" (this "Data=" occurs only once in the file)

So i need to cut the lines that are before the "=" sign and then compare these two files and then get an output stating if these 2 files are equal in a csv format file.

Its not just one file but it will be many files in 2 different folders and every first file in one folder needs to be compared with the first file in the another folder and so on..

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: It is a bit vague. Define "Unix": Bash shell only, a C program that compiles on most Unices, GNU utils, ... Also, what do you need to diff: the lines before the `Data=` line, or the string after the `=` sign on that line only? What should the output be. Please rework your example to have some explanation of what the algorithm/script should do and what the expected output would be.

Comment: Are the files in the two folders one-to-one matched, with the same filenames in each folder? e.g. if there's a myfile1111.txt in folder A is there guaranteed to be an equivalent myfile1111.txt in folder B?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should clarify your question. The answers so far suggest to use awk to get the string after the'='. However, as far as I understand your question, you want to look at all lines from the beginning until the line that starts with 'Data='.

You could use

```
sed '/^Data=/,$d' file
```

to delete all lines from the first line that matches '^Data=' to the end and feed the result into diff using the syntax that janmoesen mentioned, e.g.

```
diff <(sed '/^Data=/,$d' file1) <(sed '/Data=/,$d' file2)
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how you use awk to get the data after the "=" sign

```
awk '/Data=/{gsub("Data=","");f=1}f' file > temp1
```

that is being redirected to a temp file. do the same for file 2 that you are comparing. Then
use the command `diff` to compare the files.

Comment: Why not `awk -F 'Data=' '/^Data=/ { print $2; }'`? And if he is using a recent-ish version of Bash, he can use process substitution `diff <(awk ... file1) <(awk ... file2)`.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know how many lines you have before the "=" sign? (ie: for 2 given files, are "n" equals or not?)
Because you could use -B (or --before) option for grep.

Comment: Hi we cant tell the number of lines that are before the = sign . I am just a Functional Guy with no knowledge in coding especially Unix.. could you please help me with a complete coding?

Comment: The `-A` is just to show context on output. If the line count before the = was known and consistent I'd probably use `head`. @moustafa - if you don't know Unix or coding why is this task assigned to you? (seriously, not sarcastically)

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=$(grep "=" $1 | cut -d"=" -f2)
FILE2=$(grep "=" $2 | cut -d"=" -f2)

if [ $FILE1 = $FILE2 ]; then
    echo "Equal"
else
    echo "Not Equal."
fi
```

Simple bash script that takes the two files as command line arguments and returns Equal on equal.  Obviously you can insert any other command in place of that.

From this approach you could pipe the list of files you want to check into the second argument also.

*Edit:  Wow...necro'ed this one.